# Should I be worried about this amount of connections?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, serverless, mongodb-atlas

Recently I hosted my database on MongoDB Atlas. My API is hosted on Vercel and it’s built with Next.js so my api routes are serverless functions. I’m using [this code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/lib/dbConnect.js) for database connection. (it’s official code suggested by Next.js team).

However at peak times when a lot of users use the website at the same time I can see up to 35 active database connections (many read/write operations). Is this something normal? Shouldn’t connection count always be 1?

Thank you so much for your help!

[Connection amount picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2eKF.png)

Comment: See this link here on how to ask a question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As you're dealing with a serverless solution any concurrent requests will be served from different instances, so you'll have more connections than you would if you had a well configured server based solution.

As a result you will not be sharing the connection to the database between concurrent connections.

How sequential connections are handled can vary, I'm not certain how it works with Vercel, but with AWS Lambda you *can* reuse a connection in a subsiquent request.